# acl can't be installed on ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, apt, acl

setfacl/getfacl commands not running on my server, it says:

```
The program 'setfacl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install acl
```

when i tried to install it, it says:

```
sudo apt-get install acl

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package acl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'acl' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Whats the output of `lsb_release -r` ?

Comment: `Release: 14.04`

Comment: It's interesting http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=acl&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then try again..

Comment: @A.B. acl2 is same as acl package?,

Comment: @heemayl, i tried that but didn't work

Comment: Put the output of `apt-cache policy acl`and `apt-cache showpkg acl`  if there is an output.

Comment: I added ubunut source for the apt configuration file, `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main` and it worked now.

Comment: @heemayl That helped in my case :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following source line to apt configuration source list:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

then i can install acl normally.

Comment: Interesting, this should be provided as standard.

Comment: exactly, that was very weird as this line wasn't existed.