# Package "acl" on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, acl

I am reading [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-setting-up-the-web-server). In step 1, it says:

> We'll need [...] acl to set the right directory permissions when installing the
>   application

I wanted to check if `acl` is already installed:

```
$ dpkg -s acl
dpkg-query: package 'acl' is not installed and no information is
available Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive
files, and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their
contents.
```

Then my logic tells me to look for it with `apt-cache search`, and I run `apt-cache search acl`; it returns a list of packages, but I don't see one named strictly `acl`.

After some investigation I found similar questions on SO, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625668/acl-cant-be-installed-on-ubuntu-server) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649895/unable-to-install-acl).

I try: `apt-cache policy acl`. It returns:

```
acl:   
   Installed: (none)   
   Candidate: 2.2.52-3   
   Version table:
     2.2.52-3 500
     500 https://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

So I guess it means that is alright `acl` is installed.

I don't understand, since it seems installed when I do `apt-cache policy acl` why `dpkg -s acl` returns that it is not installed?

I've read something that I don't understand in there [in the apt-cache command doc](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-cache.html):

> apt-cache policy displays the priorities of package sources as well as
>   those of individual packages

Comment: `apt-cache policy` says it is not installed. But I don't understand how `acl` can be not installed in 16.04. It is a dependency of `systemd` o.O It is installed in 16.04 by default, for sure

Comment: @Zanna, my thoughts too...

Comment: If `acl` isn't installed then you Ubuntu is __free for all__, no security

Comment: could it because I operate from root?

Comment: I wouldn't say that @George acl is a recent, fancy addition to the traditional Linux permissions system. My thought is, OP is not running 16.04. nyluje can you clarify what version of Ubuntu you are using? (And it is a very bad idea to "operate from root" generally speaking)

Comment: when i launch: `lsb_release -a` it says:Distributor ID: Ubuntu, Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Release:        16.04, Codename:       xenial

Comment: @Zanna, thanks for your input, I've created an user attached to the admin group, to not operate from root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `acl` package provides commands for manipulating ACLs, however the actual support for ACLs is provided by `libacl1` and the filesystems implementing ACLs. The commands are entirely optional, since applications like systemd can use the library instead.

`Installed: (none)` means the package is not installed. Go ahead and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

Answer (score 4):

> Out of these SO thread I try: apt-cache policy acl. It returns:
>
> ```
> acl: Installed: (none) Candidate: 2.2.52-3 Version table: 2.2.52-3 500 500 https://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
> ```
>
> So I guess it means that is alright acl is installed.

The result of the command showed that the version of `acl` installed on your computer is *none*

Which means that *acl is **not** installed* on your computer.

When you'll execute the same command on a machine with installed version of `acl` you'll get something like:

```
 apt-cache policy acl
acl:
  Installed: 2.2.52-3
  Candidate: 2.2.52-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.52-3 500
        500 http://.......com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: How can `acl` not be installed on Ubuntu or any Linux for that matter

Comment: Thanks for your input @Yaron,`apt-cache policy acl` displays it as installed now.